# .Net Compact Framework and MultiSelect ListView

Tags: c#, .net, listview, windows-mobile, compact-framework

So I have a C# .Net Compact Framework 3.5 application with a ListView in it. That ListView should be MultiSelect (select multiple rows at once by dragging over them like in File Explorer).

Because there is no immediate property for that I send a style message to the ListView, with which I unset LVS_SINGLESEL. In my code it looks something like this:

```
public const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
public const int LVS_SINGLESEL = 0x0004;

[DllImport("coredll")] 
public static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex); 

[DllImport("coredll")] 
public static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

public static void EnableLVMultiSelect(System.Windows.Forms.ListView lv)
{
    int style = GetWindowLong(lv.Handle, GWL_STYLE);
    SetWindowLong(lv.Handle, GWL_STYLE, (style & ~LVS_SINGLESEL)); 
}
```

What this code does now, is that I can select multiple rows, if I start after the last row. But I cannot select let's say row 2, 3, 4 of 10 rows like I can in the File Explorer.
I tried it on two different devices with different Windows Mobile Versions (5.0 and 6.5) and they both behaved the same.

Is there something I am missing? Or is this not possible with the .Net Compact Framework?

Comment: Looks like a dirty hack :-) I suugest you have to develop custom control for this situation.

Comment: First, I don't think it is supported, but second, what behavior did you see when selecting multiple items.  Did it ignore the style flag and just act like a single-select, or something else?

Comment: With LVS_SINGLESEL removed from the ListView style the following worked: I could put the stylus behind or on the last row and swipe from there on up and the rows I passed were all selected as I expected. But when I start at any other row the ListView acted as if it was single-select.

Comment: To MultiSelect with the Windows Mobile device, press the `CTRL` key, select one or more items, then press the `CTRL` key again. If you know how to use the device, you don't have to write so much code.

Comment: That does work indeed (in combination with the code above ofc). But then I might as well use checkboxes because it's less of a hassle to use. I just checked with the CE Remote Spy and it turns out that the .Net ListView is just a wrapper around the systems ListView (SysListView32; the very same as the File Explorer uses). So what I'm asking _should_ be possible. Oh well - I'll just use checkboxes and get on with it. Thank you everybody that read my question and tried to help :)